# Differential equations of a plate with spherical mass load?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I would like to know the equations describing a plate surface being curved and stressed by a mass (you know, like a ball on a stretched sheet). I'm just curious :). I feel a bit confused about tensor and similar, so please explain everything (or just draw out the equations with a bit of comment, if you don't feel like that... )

P.S. The properties of the plate's material depend on some value, right? And, what's Young modulus? Does it appear in the equations?

Comment: That is a lot of questions with very little working shown on your side! For example one can quickly search Young's modulus, as it is a rather big experiment done on the limits of material stretching. So do a bit more reading and then come back and we can iterate the model. that is my opinion only though :)!

Comment: Ok! Keep in touch, I'll come back as I know more! :) Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be described by the biharmonic PDE with the thin plate spline as its fundamental solution in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Could you confirm this against (advanced) textbooks on elasticity and mathematical methods in physics and post your account of it, please?

Comment: I found this [link] (http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/ThinPlateSplines.pdf), but I don't if it can be useful. I'm sorry, my textbook doesn't tell about this...

Comment: Ok, I had some lessons online and now I can confirm that you were right! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, @user12373. Could you share the link, please, I'd love to take that online lesson myself?

Comment: That's here: [link](www.pdetolearn.com/user/lessons/15_Thin%plate.htm), but I think is down, now... If ever they'll make it online again, you'll find a section with the most important PDEs in Phisics and Engeneering, and a customized study plan to choose from, free.